# How can I remove the scale circle?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

Cant remove this scale white circle, any tips? Thanks guys
[image]

Comment: go to "Viewport Gizmos" (arc with arrow: dropdown), disable "Active Tools".  It will also remove the blue/red/green controls, but you can be sure to only scale x,y or z by hitting the x,y or 'z' character key as you scale.   But I'm not sure why anyone would bother doing so or being annoyed by the white "scale all directions" circle, as a side comment.

Comment: As an alternative, instead of clicking on the scale icon, you can just enter 's' for scale, and then the helper gizmos will not appear.  Again, you can restrict the dimension of scaling to a single axis by hitting the 'x', 'y', or 'z' key as you begin to scale.  You don't even have to be in Edit mode!

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!!